# Regex in Java is not matching anything from text file

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file with several lines

1. Category: Type of problem you're having
2. Description: Overview of the problem
3. How To Fix: Directions to fix your problem (has carriage
   returns, sometimes)
4. Related Links: Additional Resources

**There are no numbers in my list; it was the only way I could think of to make it neater...*

I've been trying to get my code to recognize all of the information between "How To Fix:" and "Related Links" when it has more than one line. I know from my research that I have to use either (?s) or Pattern.DOTALL, however neither of them seem to be working. I'm fairly new to Regex, so I'm expect is something elementary. Here is my code:

```
String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Test.txt";
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    sc1 = new Scanner(br);
                    String findingRegex = "(Description:.*)";
                    String recommRegex = "(?<=How To Fix:)(.*)(?=Related Links)";//regex I'm trying to use
                    Pattern pFinding = Pattern.compile(findingRegex);
                    Pattern pRecomm = Pattern.compile(recommRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);
                    while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
                        String clean = sc1.nextLine().trim();
                        String clean2 = clean.replaceAll("\\\\x\\p{XDigit}{2}", "");
                        Matcher mFinding = pFinding.matcher(clean2);
                        Matcher mRecomm = pRecomm.matcher(clean2);
                        while (mFinding.find()) {                        
                            System.out.println(mFinding);
                        }
                        while (mRecomm.find()){
                            System.out.println(mRecomm); //nothing prints?
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
                    fr.close();
                    System.out.println("The following data was imported: ");
                    try {
                        tbl.displayAll();
                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                        System.out.println("You have no data.");
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                    System.out.println("File named Test.txt was not located on your desktop. Program Terminated.");
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("The import operation failed. Program Terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } finally {
                    sc1.close();
                }
```

Lastly, I tested my Regex here and it worked as expected?
 [image]

MY SOLUTION:

```
String findingRegex = "(?<=Description:)(.*)(?=How To Fix)";
String recommRegex = "(?<=How To Fix:)(.*)(?=Related Links)";
Pattern pFinding = Pattern.compile(findingRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Pattern pRecomm = Pattern.compile(recommRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();

while (line != null){
  sb.append(line);
  sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
  line = br.readLine();
  }  
String newFile = sb.toString();
Matcher mFinding = pFinding.matcher(newFile);
Matcher mRecomm = pRecomm.matcher(newFile);
while (mFinding.find()) {                        
  System.out.println(mFinding);                            
  }
while (mRecomm.find()){
  System.out.println(mRecomm);
  }
```

Comment: Your title doesn't makes sense. Regular expressions don't display anything. What you mean is that your regex isn't *matching* anything.

Comment: Thanks, was having a hard time trying to summarize it; changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
String clean = sc1.nextLine().trim();
```

You are breaking your input up by line. But then you're trying to match multiple lines. There aren't multiple lines to match, because you only kept the one.

You could read the entire file into memory first, and then match against it. Or you could do something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int state = 0;
while (sc1.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = sc1.nextLine();
  if (line.contains("How To Fix:")) {
    state = 1;
  }
  if (state == 1) {
    sb.append(line);
  }
  if (line.contains("Related Links:")) {
    state = 0;
  }
}
```

(You'll need to modify this if you need to match more than once per file.)